# Could not load SSL Library problem in restful API in Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, ssl

I'm trying connect to SMS Server through the API provided by site.
I'm using this code, `ApiKey` provided via that sms server site.

I but get this error:

> Could not load SSL Library

Code:

```
procedure TMainF.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var params:TStringList;
   JsonObj:TJSONObject;
   ResStr:String;
   idHttp:TIdHTTP;
begin
 params:=TStringList.Create;
 IdHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create;
 IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication:=False;
 IdHTTP.Request.ContentType:='application/json';
 IdHTTP.Request.CharSet:='utf-8';
 IdHTTP.Request.Accept:='application-json';
 IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']:='BASIC APIKEY:'+EditApi.Text;
 try
  resStr:=IdHTTP.Post('https://sms.XSite.ir/Apiv2/User/Credit',params);
 finally
  idHttp.Free;
 end;
 JsonObj:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(ResStr) as TJSONObject;
 Memo1.Text:=ResStr;
 if JsonObj <> nil then
  try
   Memo1.Lines.Add(JsonObj.Values['Amount'].Value);
  finally
   JsonObj.Free;
  end;
 end;
```

This code should show the remaining credit

Comment: There are many reasons why you could be getting that error, the most common being either missing OpenSSL DLLs, and incorrect DLL versions. What does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` and `OpenSSLVersion()` functions report after the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

In order to invoke a SSL endpoint you have to install the **OpenSSL** libraries as explained at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/OpenSSL .

Comment: Just note that Embarcacero points Windows users to a 3rd party [OpenSSL installer](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) that uses an OpenSSL build which depends on VC++ runtimes.  The OpenSSL DLLs on Indy's [OpenSSL repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries) do not depend in VC++ runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

I installed openssl and copied the two files ( libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) to the system folders(System32 and SyswOW64 folders), but the problem remains

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have typed your response into the answer box, but it feels like a comment or forum response. Please only type answers if they work - and use comments instead to clarify details about the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).